# How do I export my armature and pose library

Tags: armature, blend-files

I am trying to export an armature and a pose library from my .blend file so that they can be loaded in to any .blend file. The ultimate goal being to start with an empty file, load the armature, load the pose library, load the mesh to parent to the armature and take it through the poses in the library.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Save it in a .blend, then either Link or Append it to the new file.

Answer (score 3):

I find it easiest to open two instances of Blender. One for the scene I am working on and 
one that has the model/material/rig, etc.

You can copy from one running instance of Blender to another using the Copy and Paste keyboard shortcuts.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>

[image]

This works well because you can select everything that you want from a scene all at once without having to dig through Blender's file navigation dialogue.

If you transfer an object that has rigging, the armature will go with it even if you did not select explicitly select the rigging.

Materials and textures will transfer over as well.

You can use this for Light and Camera setups and probably several things that still have to be thought up by someone.

BTW.  Even though OSX uses a slightly different key-combo for Copy and Paste, <kbd>Command</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>; both tend to work because Blender was programmed to recognize both.

Answer (score 2):

When you open a .blend to append or link (recommended method) you will see the internal file structure:

[image]

- Menu: File append / link
- Select the poslib from the action folder
- Menu: File append / link
- Select the rig from the object folder (not armature)

After that you can select the poselib in the properties:

[image]

Note that pose libraries are just actions and can also be found and edited in *Action Editor Mode* of the *Dopesheet*.

If you decide to use linked files, you might also be interested in the *Edit Linked Library* addon which must be enabled in the *User Preferences* and allows to switch quickly between your work- and library .blend file.

[image]

Related:

[how to copy a rig to another mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7461/how-to-copy-a-rig-to-another-mesh)